# multiple audio, auto stop other when current is playing with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, audio-player

I have more than 5 audio players with `audioplayer.js` on a html5 page.

Does anyone has a simple script in js to pause all other players when the current player is playing ?

jQuery:

```
$( function(){
   $("audio").audioPlayer();
});
```

Library

```
https://osvaldas.info/examples/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly/audioplayer.js
```

I have tried as below

```
window.player = $('audio')[0];
$('.audioplayer-playpause').click(function () {
    if (player.paused) {
        player.play();
    } else {
        player.pause();
    }
});
```

I have made a jsFiddle just to easeout things and below is the link:

[JS Fiddle for Audio Player](https://jsfiddle.net/8u2pcj83/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below code.I have tested it in JS Fiddle & it is working :) :)

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8u2pcj83/19/)

Put this code in Javascript & remove yours.

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    // get all <audio> tag elements in the page.
    var allAudios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    // Iterate through all players and pause them, except for
    // the one who fired the "play" event ("target")
    for(var i = 0; i<allAudios.length; i++){
        if(allAudios[i] != e.target){
            allAudios[i].pause();
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Noooo.. you have removed plugin initialization. Please do not modify player code

Comment: And i know this code already.. this does not work on this player

Comment: why to use window as a scope?